# AdView on Custom View in Android

Tags: android, admob, adview

I am creating a simple View for a game I am making. I have a Title Screen that I want to show ads on using the AdView.

in my constructor I have this:

```
public TitleView(Context context) 
{
    super(context);

    myContext = context;
    titleGraphic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.title_graphic);
    playButtonUp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.play_button_up);
    playButtonDown = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.play_button_down);

    layout = new LinearLayout(myContext);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    adView = new AdView((Activity)myContext, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "a151967e40a4400");
    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    layout.addView(adView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    this.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

In my onDraw method I have the following:

```
    layout.measure(screenW, screenH);
    layout.layout(0, 0, screenW, screenH);
    layout.draw(canvas);
```

The problem is, the graphics are loading, I see the adView request in LogCat but I am never seeing the ADs displayed in the app. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you seeing log messages for the ad impression being served? Ie that the Ad request actually found an ad for you? Also what is TitleView, where is 'layout' defined and how is 'layout' being attached to your Activity's root layout?

Comment: I completely changed the way I was doing it. I created a layout for the activity and add the title view in the XML layout itself. I thought it would be easier than trying to add the TitleView to the layout programmatically.

Comment: Sounds like a much better approach :-)